# ios - MKMapView dont show Current Location

Tags: ios, mapkit

In MKMapKit's map view control, i am showing the user's current location. A blue circle is being shown as the location of current user. On tapping, it shows an annotation view "Current Location", but instead i want to show some text in the call out. How can I change the text text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        ((MKUserLocation *)annotation).title = @"My Current Location";
        return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view
    }
.
.
.
.
.
}
```